# Can’t see rp3 samba share from a win10 machine

Tags: pi-3, windows-iot, samba

I have a need to share a pi folder with three windows computers.  I have been 2/3 successful.  I have installed samba on the RP3 and can see a shared folder on the pi from a win7 and a win10 computer, but the main computer, a win10, can not see the pi share even though it CAN connect to the pi via VNC.  Also, I can ping the RP3 from all three win computers.  I have checked and all three are in the home group and haven’t found any difference between the win10 that can see the share and the one that can’t.

Can anyone suggest other things to look at on the win10 that can not see the  RP3 share?  I am using Debian 9 on the pi and it has been updated and upgraded.

Comment: Don't you think you stand a better chance of getting help on a windows  site?

Comment: I would temporary turn off the firewall on the win10

Comment: funny:  I was told on a windows site that this was a "known" Raspberry pi problem, so I now I am really confused.

Comment: I could be wrong but I can not confirm this as a "known" RPi issue. You say on 2 of 3 PCs you can see the shared folder on the RPi. But not on PC #3 ("main computer", whatever that means). Do you have a specific configuration on your RPi for client #3? If yes: adjust it. If not: check the config on #3.

Comment: I can't confirm it ether.  #3 is the same configuration as the other two which supports the idea of it being a setup issue on #3 (BTW, I access my CNC's and 3D printer via VNC from #3 (shop computer) and rarely need to access these machines from the other two, therefore the "main computer" designation).  I will keep trying to find an issue with the configuration on #3 and describe any solution here.

Comment: additionally I would read the respective logfiles on the RPi (i.e. `sudo tail -f /var/log/samba/NAME.log`) while each client requests access to the shared folder, maybe there is a difference visible (maybe `grep` for the hostname could be helpful)

Comment: You got samba2 running? Windows 10 may need some extra things enabling, ie network browsing.

Answer (score 1):

I just battled this issue.  They disabled SMB1 in Windows 10 by default due to ransomeware issues.  Try enabling it via Windows Features if you want to chance opening the system up.

Comment: There’s really nothing on that computer that I couldn’t install in a few minutes, so I’m not to worried about it.  I will check out your suggestion.  Thanks